# Why GetProcAddress() is not working?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have quite novice to DLL programming.

I have created a DLL project as,

In DLL project `SimpleH.h`

```
namespace ME{
    class base
    {
    public:
        static __declspec(dllexport) void Hello();
    };
}
__declspec(dllexport) void HelloWorld();
```

`DLL.cpp`

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "SimpleH.h"
using namespace std;
namespace ME
{
    void base::Hello()
        {
            cout << "Hello World\n";
        }
}
void HelloWorld()
{
    cout << "Hello I am world\n";
}
```

I have created an `.exe`.

`Main.exe`

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;
    typedef void (*FunctionFunc)();
    typedef void (*FunctionAno)();
    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {

        FunctionFunc _FunctionFunc;
        FunctionAno _FunctionAno;
        HINSTANCE hInstLibrary = LoadLibrary(L"MyDLL.dll");
        if(hInstLibrary)
        {
            /*Problem Happens here*/
            _FunctionFunc = (FunctionFunc)GetProcAddress(hInstLibrary, "Hello");
            _FunctionAno = (FunctionFunc)GetProcAddress(hInstLibrary, "HelloWorld");
/**/
            if(_FunctionFunc)
            {
                _FunctionFunc(); 
            }
            if(_FunctionAno)
            {
                _FunctionAno();
            }
          DWORD error = ::GetLastError();
          if (error)
          {
            LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
            LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;

            FormatMessage(
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
            NULL,
            error,
            MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
            (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
            0, NULL );

          }
        }
        FreeLibrary(hInstLibrary);
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

hInstance is getting updated properly.
But the `GetProcAddress()` are not getting updated.
Please help me.
Where is it going wrong?

Comment: You might want to read about [name mangling in C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B).

Comment: possible duplicate of [GetProcAddress cannot find my functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601908/getprocaddress-cannot-find-my-functions)

Comment: @librik some kind of duplicate, BUT the extern "C" trick won't work for the static member function (or will it?)

Answer (score 4):

Exported functions have "decorated names". Use DUMPBIN to see them.

DUMPBIN /EXPORTS Your.dll

Comment: Where do I need to write it? Is it to be in `Propoties` or in `CPP` file?

Comment: Use the decorated names in the GetProcAddress calls.

Answer (score 2):

Your function and method names are [*mangled* according to Visual C++ rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B_Name_Mangling).

If you use `DUMPBIN /EXPORTS MyDLL.dll` from the command line, you will read some identifier names like:

> ```
>      1    0 00001000 ?Hello@base@ME@@SAXXZ
>      2    1 00001020 ?HelloWorld@@YAXXZ
> ```

So, for example, `HelloWorld` is actually exported as `?HelloWorld@@YAXXZ`. So `GetProcAddress()` can't find the original identifier. Use **`extern "C"`** to avoid name mangling on `HelloWorld`:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void HelloWorld();
```

More details on proper ways to export C++ classes from DLL can be found in [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLL).